# Laravel 5: Adding new item instead of editing

Tags: php, html, laravel

When I edit an item in my list of `projects` it wont edit the current project, but it will add a new one with leaving the 'original one' has how it was instead of editing the project

What am I doing wrong with my code?

Controller:

```
    class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    private $project;

    public function __construct(Project $project){

        $this->project = $project;

//        $this->project  = $project
//            ->with('user');
    }

    public function getUsersTotal () {
        $project_users = DB::table('users')
            ->select('browser')
            ->groupBy('browser')
            ->get();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $projects = Project::get();

        return view('project.index', array('projects' => $projects));
    }


    public function create()
    {
        return view('project.create');
    }


    public function store(CreateProjectRequest $request, Project $project)
    {
        $project->create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('project.index');
    }


    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function edit($id)
    {
        $project = $this->project->find($id);


        return view('project.edit', ['project' => $project, 'id' => 'edit']);
    }



    public function update(CreateProjectRequest $request, $project)
    {
        $this->project->fill($request->input())->save();

        return redirect('project');
    }


    public function destroy($projectId)
    {
        $this->project->destroy($projectId);

        return redirect('project');
    }

}
```

Comment: show the whole controller, or at least the update method

Comment: excuse me, I didn't even notice. Stupid. I edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try following...

```
   public function update(CreateProjectRequest $request, $project)
    {

        $project = $this->project->find($project);
        $project->fill($request->input())->save();

        return redirect('project');
    }
```

You must provide a project which needs to be edited.

Comment: I don't think this would work. I would be surprised, but the problem is he is creating a new project every time... Which you're trying to fix. In reality he can just get the project id and do a find on that based on the request. Which is what he should do.

Comment: The problem was he didn't select project needs to be updated and that is why it was creating new project.